# Why does this case statement not work?

Tags: sql

Why does this case statement not work? My table is defined as below. I want the case to return true when M = "M" or false if it is not. Something does not seem to look right with this CASE statement but this is the simple case statement. But I thought that could be as many WHEN values as needed but in this cases there is only True or False and it does not appear that there could be anything different.

The input should be all of the M column in the row. I am expecting the output to be one row since I only have one row that has an M value in the column. I am not certain if the case statement should return false in this case.

```
    CASE M = "M <-- is this is what the criteria is based on
```

I found that this is not the case however from the post below. When i meant that this did not look right I was referring two the fact that the WHEN portion of the code

```
    WHEN true THEN something
```

just did not look like it normally does.

Code:

```
select CASE M = "M"
       WHEN true  THEN "PPP"
       WHEN false THEN "False -- Look Again!"
       ELSE "Not Found"
       END  
from Bat;
```

Image:

[image]

New Code:

```
select *, 
       CASE 
       WHEN M = 'M'  THEN 

             Case
                 when O = 'O' then 'you found a double (MM)' <--Compiles but does not show result
             End    

       WHEN M is null THEN 'False -- Look Again!'       
       END as 'What is this value'
from Bat;
```

That fixed the first problem but you can embed case statements N deep I would think so if i search again on O it should return a correct. But the first case returns only one record. So my second case would have to search in the record correct.

Comment: What about it isn't working? What input are you giving it (example row data), what output do you expect, and what output are you actually getting? We can't debug "something does not seem to look right" without you explaining what that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal way to write this is:

```
select (CASE WHEN M = 'M' THEN 'PPP'
             WHEN M <> 'M' THEN 'False -- Look Again!'
             ELSE 'Not Found'
        END)  
from Bat;
```

or:

```
select (CASE WHEN M is null then 'Not Found'
             WHEN M = 'M' THEN 'PPP'
             ELSE 'False -- Look Again!'
        END)  
from Bat;
```

If I had to guess, your version has unexpected behavior for `NULL` values, but it is hard to say without knowing what you expect or what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Change it like this

```
select CASE 
       WHEN M = 'M'  THEN 'PPP'
       WHEN M is null THEN 'False -- Look Again!'       
       ELSE "Not Found"
       END  
from Bat;
```